# install python MySQLdb to python3 not python

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, installation

i have Ubuntu and installed python3 since my script is written in it. Since I use MYSQL with MySQLdb, I installed

`apt-get install python-mysqldb`

however this installed MySQLdb to Python (which is 2.6 on Ubuntu) and not to Python3.

1. How can I install MySQLdb for Python3
2. Should I use it at all or switch to PyMSQL

Sorry, I have just started working with Python today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's [not ported](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/) to python3 yet.

Answer (score 9):

1- You can use this command
`sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb`

It worked for me.

2- also you can install `pip install PyMySQL`.

### Then add lines to `__init__.py` file

```
# __init__.py file

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: For me too! Thanks!

Comment: it's works to install but can't used, not listed in modul after installed successfully

Answer (score 4):

MySQLdb is not yet Python3 compatible, but
[oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/), a Python-MySQL driver, is.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3/wiki/Install-on-Linux

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

How to install MySQLdb for Python2

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

How to install MySQLdb for Python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a success for me on linux (UBUNTU) and anaconda:

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
( it get mysql_config )

then

pip3 install git+git://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3

that's it...

More info on https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3/wiki/Install-on-Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to switch from MySQLDB then I recommend you to use **MySQL connector Python**

Why ?

- it work with both Python 2 and 3
- Because it is official Oracle driver for MySQL for working with Python.
- It is purely written in Python
- You can also use  C extension to connect to MySQL.
- MySQL Connector/Python is implementing the MySQL Client/Server protocol completely in Python. This means you don't have to compile anything or MySQL doesn't even have to be installed on the machine.
- Also, it has great support for connection pooling